# Assign value to a column based on other column value in excel

Tags: excel, statistics

I am trying to assign `A`, `B`, `C` values to a new column based on these three conditions:

- `A` if the cell value is `100=<x<=75`
- `B` if the cell value is `75=<x<=50`
- `C` if the cell value is `50<=x<=20`

I am using this formula:

```
=AND((75<=C17)*100>=C17)
```

Which does the job, how could I rename it to be `A` rather than `True`, and pass multiple conditions in one formula for `A`, `B`, `C` values? ( for some reason excel changes my `,` sign to `*` in the formula )

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: You need the IF function to custom the output. Also, what happens if the number is 75? because with your actual conditions, it can be A or B. Same for 50

Comment: I think by default excel stops when the first condition is met, right?

Comment: *by default excel stops when the first condition is met*. Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using `IF` as suggested by @Foxfire And Burns And Burns:

```
=IF(C2>=75;"A";IF(C2>=50;"B";IF(C2>=20;"C")))
```

Comment: What happens if the value is 19 or lower?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, nothing, as per the request of my colleague nothing should be assigned to a row if it's below 19. In this case, 'FALSE' is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a dynamic range using vlookup with approximate match

[image]

Comment: Don't want to create additional columns with values, but will keep that in mind, thanks.